# Is it possible to add PointCut to ModelAndView method?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I tried to use PointCut to perform some post action after `ModelAndView.setViewName`, but it seems that it never triggers:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class TestAspect {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView.*(..))")
    public void testPointCut() {

    }

    @After("testPointCut()")
    public void afterPointCut(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        logger.debug("afterPointCut");
    }
}
```

If I change the `execution` part to some class of my own, this point cut works.

So what is the correct way to add `PointCut` to `ModelAndView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a Spring user, but what I know about Spring AOP is that you can only apply it to Spring components. The class `ModelAndView` is not derived from any Spring core component class or annotated by anything making it such, it is a simple POJO. As such you cannot target it by Spring AOP pointcuts. You should rather target something within the reach of Spring AOP.

The alternative would be to unpack the big gun and use full AspectJ LTW (load-time weaving) which is not limited to Spring components.

Comment: sorry for being so late, I thought there could be a better solution for this, but after a month-long waiting, I guess you are right about this, btw I solved my problem with an old school way: using a wrapper.

Comment: Configuring Spring to use [AspectJ with LTW (load-time weaving)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) would have been a matter of minutes or maybe hours, depending on how complex your setting is. I thought you might want to give it a spin. But a wrapper is also nice. I guess you made the wrapper a Spring component and then apply AOP to that wrapper, right?

Comment: You are almost right, I'll try LTW another time, because I don't want to use a sledge hammer to crack a nut, thanks again!